# Visual Studio Solution Explorer like experience for VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Sorry in advance if this is not the right place to ask but can someone help me customise VS Code to work similar to Visual Studios Solution Explorer?

In Visual Studio we have the Solution Explorer which lists all files but also there are 2 very handy view filters; found in the title bar of the Solution Explorer panel.

- Open Files Filter
- Pending Changes Filter
- if neither is selected then default to show all files in the solution

Ideally I want the Workspace view that lists all files in VSCode, but also a toggle to only list 'Open' files. (I'm less interested in Pending Changes).

I'm aware of the Open Editors view but I find this difficult to navigate since it's a flat view and isn't a nested directory structure. When every file is called view.html in its own folder it's a nightmare to eyeball the list of files.

Also I think toggling between "all" and "open" files would be easier than going up and down between 2 panels when you want to open something new.

So is this possible, does anyone know of a way to customise vscode to get this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the SCM tab shows you the modified files for each workspace

Comment: @rioV8 ok didnt see that, thanks! and i can see it has a tree view toggle! if only the open editors tab had this

Comment: looks like its all ready been raised https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81544